# how to interpret the rows and columns of H2O confusion matrix

Tags: h2o, confusion-matrix

it's said 
Vertical : Actual
Across : Predicted

does it mean the rows are actual (i=1 for No,i=2 for Yes)
or the reverse

Answer (score 1):

There is a JIRA ticket [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5911) to help with the confusion by printing a clearer message. Currently this message is only available for the multinomial case but will be added for binary classification problems as well.

For example if you run the confusion matrix on the iris dataset which solves a multi-class problem you will get the following output.

```
Confusion Matrix: Row labels: Actual class; Column labels: Predicted class
                Iris-setosa Iris-versicolor Iris-virginica  Error      Rate
Iris-setosa              42               0              0 0.0000 =  0 / 42
Iris-versicolor           0              37              2 0.0513 =  2 / 39
Iris-virginica            0               1             35 0.0278 =  1 / 36
Totals                   42              38             37 0.0256 = 3 / 117
```

so to answer your question: the row labels are the Actual class, and the column labels are the Predicted class.